# Qual é o sentido de um atributo ser private e static ao mesmo tempo em uma classe?

Tags: c#, java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando sobre o `design pattern` `singleton`, e em um trecho de código em `java`, me deparei com uma situação em que fiquei com dúvida. Segue abaixo o trecho do código:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static Conexao instance = new Conexao();

    public static Conexao getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Conexao() {
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://endereco_do_banco.ws", "login", "senha");
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Minha dúvida está no trecho `private static Conexao instance = new Conexao();` , qual é o sentido de criar um atributo `private` e `static` ao mesmo tempo? Se o atribuímos como `private` é porque queremos que ele não seja visível para outras classes, e colocando ele como `static`, estaríamos deixando-o visível para demais classes, isso não é contraditório?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Se o atribuímos como private é porque queremos que ele não seja visível para outras classes, e colocando ele como static, estaríamos deixando-o visível para demais classes, isso não é contraditório?

Embora a sua definição do modificador de acesso `private` esteja correta, você errou na definição do modificador `static` (vou explicar em seguida o que ele realmente faz) e o que você disse sobre ele caberia apenas para descrever o modificador de acesso `public`. Você provavelmente se confundiu nas definições.

O modificador `static` faz com que um membro declarado com ele seja acessível através do tipo onde ele foi declarado e não através de uma instância do tipo. Ou seja, uma propriedade ou um método declarado como `static` pode ser acessado diretamente sem a necessidade de que você instancie a classe onde ele foi declarado (`Classe1.Propriedade1 = "Oi";` ou `Classe1.Metodo1();`).

Note que quando é necessário criar uma instância da classe quando o membro não possui o modificador `static` (`var obj = new Classe1(); obj.Propriedade1 = "Oi"; obj.Metodo();`).

Já o modificador de acesso `public` esse sim, deixa os membros de um tipo (classe) ou um tipo em si, acessível sem nenhuma restrição.

Recomendo que você dê uma lida na definição do modificador [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) para compreende-lo melhor, e também na definição do modificador de acesso [`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx).

> qual é o sentido de criar um atributo `private` e `static` ao mesmo tempo?

Não acredito que agora seja necessário responder essa primeira pergunta, mas vamos lá.

A resposta é simples, o padrão de design *Singleton* requer que seja feito dessa maneira.

Conforme descrito no artigo do Wikipédia, para implementar o padrão a classe precisa possuir as seguintes características:

- Um campo privado e estático precisa ser criado na classe para armazenar a única instância da classe que será distribuída pela aplicação;
- Um método público e estático que irá retornar a instância da classe que está armazenada no campo definido no ponto anterior;
- Instâncias da classe só poderão ser criadas dentro dela mesma através do método definido no ponto anterior, para isso é necessário que a classe possua um construtor privado.

Mas note que a definição de campos como `private static` não é restrita apenas a esse padrão, você pode se deparar com situações dentro de um projeto que podem vir a se beneficiar de um campo declarado dessa maneira.

Comment: Entendi @Zignd, muito obrigado pela explicação! Agora percebi que minha visão sobre static está completamente errada, preciso estudar mais sobre isso.

Comment: De nada, pelo menos consegui te ajudar. (^-^)

Comment: Mais uma dúvida, mas qual é o sentido de se atribuir um modificador de acesso, como o private por exemplo, a um membro static? Em que ponto que o acesso private limitaria o acesso a um membro static?

Comment: @Duds a vantagem de fazer isso é que você tem controle de como oferecer essa instância estática. Você pode por exemplo querer realizar algumas operações nessa instância antes de repassa-la para quem a solicitou. Para fazer isso você pode criar uma propriedade que só possua apenas o `get` e modificar a instância como quiser dentro do bloco `get` antes de retorna-la.

Answer (score 10):

Não é porque sua definição está errada. O entendimento do que o `private` faz está correto.

Mas o `static` não diz que está visível para outras classes, ele diz que o membro pertence à classe e não a uma instância da classe. Ele não tem a ver com visibilidade, ele tem a ver com a propriedade do dado, com o local onde ele será armazenado e portanto através de qual componente da linguagem ele será acessado. Ele é um modificador de escopo. Ele define o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) do membro.

Assim como membros da instância podem ser públicos ou privados os membros da classe também podem.

Um campo estático é aquele que está disponível em uma classe de forma única para toda a aplicação. Ele não está vinculado a uma instância da classe. Ele pertence a classe em si e é compartilhado por todas as instâncias (objetos) **desta classe** criadas durante a execução da aplicação, o tempo de vida é toda a aplicação. Enquanto que o tempo de vida de um membro de instância é o mesmo do tempo de vida instância a qual ele pertence.

Um campo estático existe dentro da classe, mas a sua visibilidade é definida por outro modificador.

Um campo privado é aquele que só pode ser visto/acessado dentro da classe ,tudo que é privado é detalhe de implementação. Significa que você não quer que ninguém saiba como é internamente (não no sentido se segredo industrial) dando a chance de mudar quando quiser, do jeito que quiser.

O que é público faz parte da API, é algo que você se compromete a manter estável, afinal qualquer um pode acessar aquilo. Você não tem controle quem acessou e de que forma.

Escopo e visibilidade são coisas diferentes. O local da existência do dado é o escopo. Onde pode existir uma requisição de acesso a este dado, ou seja, onde ele pode ser acessado, é a visibilidade.

E é simples testar e verificar isto já que você tem dois membros estáticos cada um com uma visibilidade diferente. Os dois são variáveis pertencentes à classe e não a uma instância. Já o `getConnection()` é de instância.

Tente acessar o campo `instance` de outro local fora desta classe. Pode fazer da forma que quiser (exceto por reflexão ou outro truque que passa por cima da linguagem:) ), não dá, só acessa dentro da classe.

Por outro lado o método `getInstance()` é estático e público. Tente acessar de fora. Consegue.

É só isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas então @bigown, se ele tem a ver com a propriedade do dado e com o local onde ele será armazenado, qual é o sentido de uma static ter acesso do tipo private? No que um modificador private influencia no acesso a um membro do tipo static?

Comment: Eu melhorei, não sei se consigo ser mais claro que isto. Mas aparentemente você achou que a outra resposta está mais clara. Eu não acho que ela explica alguma coisa do que você perguntou, mas tudo bem. Pra falar a verdade ela mais desinforma.

Comment: Elabore sobre o fato da minha resposta "desinformar", @bigown. Agora fiquei curioso.

Comment: A resposta não responde exatamente o que foi perguntado. Mas se o AP acha que sim, vai se fazer o que . Mas o problema maior é o comentário que fala em "instância estática" (?!?!?) e tudo ali não faz sentido.

Comment: Essa é a resposta certa. Não tem nada de errado na outra resposta, mas ela não responde a pergunta que foi feita. +1

Comment: Pronto, fiz uma correção na minha resposta, agora ela está respondendo a pergunta. @jbueno

Comment: @Zignd Julgo que a única resposta que responde cabalmente à pergunta "Qual é o sentido de um atributo ser private e static ao mesmo tempo" é a minha.

Answer (score 5):

As razões para `private static` são:

- `private` por não se quer que ele seja visivel fora da classe.
- `static` porque não se pode referenciar um campo não `static` num método `static` como é o caso de `getInstance()`

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, sei que já se passaram anos, mas outras pessoas podem ter a mesma dúvida.

A resposta do nosso amigo Zignd é a melhor, mais correta, mas difícil de entender.

1. Sua definição de static está errado. Mas porque você acha isso?
   Motivo: em **C** uma FUNÇÃO static é visível apenas ao seu arquivo de origem. Em **Java** um método static quer dizer **outra coisa**.
2. Em Java, um método static quer dizer que ele é ÚNICO para todos as seus Objetos. Faz sempre a mesma coisa.
   Logo, para chamar um método static não é necessário instanciar um objeto.
   Exemplo:

.

```
public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                ClasseB objB;
                objB  = new ClasseB(); // Não precisa instanciar objB para usar getValor
                System.out.println("Ola\n");
                //
                System.out.println("Valor= " + ClasseB.getValor()); // Funcionaria mesmo sem instanciar objB, pois está chamando o metodo static.
                System.out.println("Valor= " + objB.getValor()); // Está chamando o objB, logo só funciona se instanciar obj. (objB  = new ClasseB();)
                System.out.println("Valor= " + ClasseB.getValor());


        }
}

class ClasseB {

    private static int valor = 0;

    public static int getValor()
    {
        valor ++;
        return valor;
    }

    public ClasseB()
    {

    }
}
```

Saída:

```
MEU@PC:~/tmp$ 
MEU@PC:~/tmp$ javac Main.java
MEU@PC:~/tmp$ java Main
Ola

Valor= 1
Valor= 2
Valor= 3
```

System.out.println é um método static, por isso não é necessário que você o instancia entes de utilizar. (Fazer System system = new System());

3. Variaveis static são parecidas em C e em Java.

Pense nelas como variáveis GLOBAIS, para todos os objetos, mas só são acessível dentro do escopo onde foi criada. No caso de java, dentro da sua Classe (ou objeto) e **globais ENTRE os objetos**.

O que quer dizer? Ao chamar o programa, a variável static é criada. Ela ficará na memória até que o programa finalizar.
Mas ela é inacessível fora do escopo dela (das chaves onde foi criada {}).

Por isso é necessário

```
public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                ClasseA objA = new ClasseA();
                ClasseA objB = new ClasseA();

                System.out.println("System.out.print nao precisa de NEW por ser static.\n");

                System.out.println("ClasseA.valorStatico= " + ClasseA.getValorStatico());
                System.out.println("objA.valorStatico= " + objA.getValorStatico());
                System.out.println("ClasseA.valorStatico= " + ClasseA.getValorStatico());
                // System.out.println("objA.valorStatico= " + ClasseA.getValorLocal()); <- Erro de compilacao, método não é estatico.
                System.out.println("objA.valorLocal= " + objA.getValorGlobalLocal());
                System.out.println("objA.valorLocal= " + objA.getValorGlobalLocal());
                System.out.println("objA.valorStatico= " + objA.getValorStatico());

// PARA B
                System.out.println("ClasseA.valorStatico= " + ClasseA.getValorStatico());
                System.out.println("objB.valorStatico= " + objA.getValorStatico());
                System.out.println("ClasseA.valorStatico= " + ClasseA.getValorStatico());
                // System.out.println("objB.valorStatico= " + ClasseB.getValorLocal()); <- Erro de compilacao, método não é estatico.
                System.out.println("objB.valorLocal= " + objA.getValorGlobalLocal());
                System.out.println("objB.valorLocal= " + objA.getValorGlobalLocal());
                System.out.println("objB.valorStatico= " + objB.getValorStatico());

        }
}

class ClasseA {

    private static int valorStatico = 0;
    private int valorGlobalLocal =0;

    public static int getValorStatico()
    {
        return valorStatico++;
    }
    public int getValorGlobalLocal()
    {
        return valorGlobalLocal++;
    }

    public ClasseA()
    {


    }
}
```

Assim teremos a seguinte saída:

```
java Main
System.out.print nao precisa de NEW por ser static.

ClasseA.valorStatico= 0
objA.valorStatico= 1
ClasseA.valorStatico= 2
objA.valorLocal= 0
objA.valorLocal= 1
objA.valorStatico= 3
ClasseA.valorStatico= 4
objB.valorStatico= 5
ClasseA.valorStatico= 6
objB.valorLocal= 2
objB.valorLocal= 3
objB.valorStatico= 7
```

Repare, ClasseA.valorStatico é incrementada tanto quando é chamada por objA, objB ou ClasseB.

No meu entendimento, o simples fato de você fazer a variável **instance** como **static**, já é um Singleton.
Estes exemplos de cóigos de Singleton são exemplos para várias linguagens. Em Java
só instanciar como var como static, se var = null, então precisa criar a conexao com o DB.

Agora, o private Conexao() (private no Construtor), faz com que sua classe nunca seja instanciada por outra classe, somente por ela mesmo. Logo, somente um método static (da prória classe Conexao) consegue alocar o objeto. Isso serve pra ter controle total sobre como criar o objeto.

Se em minha classe o contrutor fosse private:

```
classe ClasseB
{ 
...
    private ClasseB()
    {


    }
}
```

Nunca seria possível instanciar externamente B:

```
ClasseB varB = new ClasseB() // daria erro
```