# Explicação em método construtor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Tenho umas dúvidas no método construtor de uma classe que estou vendo como exemplo, se alguém puder explicar agradeço.

```
private static IList<Categoria> categorias = new List<Categoria>()
        {
            new Categoria() {
            CategoriaId = 1,
            Nome = "Notebooks"},

            new Categoria() {
            CategoriaId = 2,
            Nome = "Monitores"},

            new Categoria() {
            CategoriaId = 3,
            Nome = "Impressoras"},

            new Categoria() {
            CategoriaId = 4,
            Nome = "Mouses"},

            new Categoria() {
            CategoriaId = 5,
            Nome = "Desktops"},
        };
```

1º dúvida - para que serve a palavra `static` nesse caso?

2º dúvida - por que foi declarado categorias como `IList` de `Categoria` e recebeu uma `List`, ou seja, qual a diferença de `List` para `IList`?

Comment: Se colocar mais trechos, pode dar mais contexto e obter uma resposta melhor. Mas parece que essas duas perguntas já possuem respostas aqui. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/101 (é Java, mas funciona igual), http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101. Complemento: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139045/101. Para o `static`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99603/101. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101 (java, mas é igual).    Exemplo de uso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134576/101

Comment: Eu queria saber pq nesse exemplo foi usado o IList para declarar categorias, não poderia ter usado somente o List direto ? no caso: private static List<Categoria> categorias = new List<Categoria>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/listt-or-ilistt

Comment: Ninguém achou que deveria fechar, dei uma resposta que pode ser um pouco mais útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `static`

O `static` indica que aquele membro faz parte da [classe e não do objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101) a ser criado para aquela classe - a instância - e só existirá em toda aplicação, ao contrário das instâncias de objetos da classe que aquele membro estará em cada objeto criado.

Uma explicação mais completa pode ser vista em [Qual é o sentido de um atributo ser private e static ao mesmo tempo em uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99603/101). Também pode ver melhor a diferença entre o membro estático e o de instância (é Java, mas no C# funciona igual): [Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96710/101). Um exemplo real pode ajudar entender: [Como armazenar dados na memória RAM e fazer com que eles ficam disponiveis para qualquer módulo ou classe da minha aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134576/101). Em C# o `static` é igual, mas algumas práticas ali são diferentes.

## Interface X classe

Imagino que sabe que o `IList` é uma [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) e o `List` é uma [classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101) concreta. Dizer que ali tem um `IList` é uma forma mais geral de usar o `List` que implementa o `IList`. è interessante porque não obriga o uso de `List`, um dia pode mudar para outra classe mais adequada que implemente `IList`. Além disso todo acesso ao objeto ali só pode ser feito nos métodos listados em `IList` que é uma certa proteção do que pode fazer.

Isto ocorre seguindo uma prática muito comum para generalizar os algoritmos e  estruturas de dados sem se preocupar com o detalhe da implementação: [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Uma explicação específica sobre ele podem ser lida em [Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101).

Também pode ser útil ler [ArrayList x List](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/101).

Answer (score 0):

boa tarde,vamos a resposta
1. O método foi declaro estático para poder ser usado dentro da classe sem à necessidade de instanciar a classe, como se trata de um método que sempre retorna o mesmo resultado e não guarda estádo (stateless) não tem necessidade de ser instânciado. 
2. Ilist é uma interface, que List implementa ele, por isto que você pdoe dizer que seu método tem um retorno do super tipo (ILIst) e retorna qualquer tipo que implemente ele (no caso List)